# Set cardinality with $\frac{1}{n(A \cap B)}+\frac{1}{n(A \cup B)}+\frac{1}{n(P(A\cup B))} = \frac{19}{24}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, contest-math

> Let $n(X)$ be the cardinality of a finite set $X$ and $P(X)$ the set of all the subsets of $X$. If $A$ and $B$ are two finite sets such that:
>
> $$\frac{1}{n(A \cap B)}+\frac{1}{n(A \cup B)}+\frac{1}{n(P(A\cup B))} = \frac{19}{24}$$
>
> prove that $A=B$.

I know that the number of subsets is $2$ to the power of the number of elements, so:

$$n(P(A\cup B)) = 2^{n(A\cup B)}$$

I'm not sure this might help in proving $A=B$, I believe I have to show that $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$, because we don't know anything about the elements in $A$ or $B$, but how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $n(A\cap B)=x,n(A\cup B)=y, n(P(A\cup B))=2^y$. Rewriting the given equation gives

$$\frac{xy+x2^y+y2^y}{xy2^y}=\frac{19}{3\times2^3}$$

Now assume $x$ has $m$ two factors $x=2^mx'$, and $y$ has $n$ two factors i.e. $y=2^ny'$ and thus $x',y'$ are odd numbers. After simplifying the LHS to the two factors in nominator and denominator we get

$$\frac{xy+x2^y+y2^y}{xy2^y}=\frac{x'y'2^{m+n}+x'2^{m+y}+y'2^{y+n}}{x'y'2^{y+m+n}}=\frac{x'y'+x'2^{y-n}+y'2^{y-m}}{x'y'2^y}=\frac{19}{3\times2^3}$$

This means $y=3=y'\times2^n$ and $x'y'=3z$ for some integer $z$ (we simplified only to the factors of two, so maybe more simplifications is in progress, we don't know, so we call it $z$). Therefore $n=1$ and $y'=3$. With this new found evidence we can say

$$\frac{3x+8x+24}{24x}=\frac{19}{24}\Rightarrow 11x+24=19x\Rightarrow x=3$$

Therefore $n(A\cap B)=n(A\cup B)$. But we know $n(A\cap B)\le n(A\cup B)$ with equality when $A=B$.

Comment: (+1) Just wanted to add that I think we can solve $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{2^y}=\frac{19}{24}$ a little easier if we notice that $x\leq y\leq {2^y}\Rightarrow \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{2^y}\leq \frac{3}{x}\Rightarrow x \in \{2,3\}$ and now it's easy casework.

Comment: Yup, that's a nice solution indeed, why don't you add it too?

Comment: It would have to borrow the important steps of the solution from yours :)

Answer (score 1):

Credit for the main steps goes to [K.K.McDonald](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/302349/k-k-mcdonald).

If we set $x=n(A\cap B)$, $y=n(A\cup B)$, then the given equation is

$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{2^y}=\frac{19}{24}$$

Notice that $x\leq y\leq 2^y$, so

$$\frac{19}{24}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{2^y} \geq \frac{3}{x}\Rightarrow x\leq \frac{72}{19}$$

We can not have $x=1$, so $x \in \{2,3\}$. If $x = 2$, the equation becomes:

$$\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{2^y}=\frac{7}{24}$$

so $y > 3$ and $\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{2^y} \leq \frac{2}{y}$, so $y \in \{4,5,6\}$, but none of this check, so no solution for $x=2$. If $x=3$, in a similar manner we find $y=3$, so $n(A\cup B)=n(A\cap B)$, which means $A=B$.